# Excel formula - copy everyother row from 2 sheets

Tags: excel, vba, formula

I know how to use a formula to reference in text from other sheet however, when dragging along its picking up each column by sequence, I need this to be able to copy over every other 1. I.E. B19,D19,F19,H19,J19... ETC.

Can anyone help?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

to get the pattern use INDEX()

```
=INDEX('Initial data sheet'!19:19,(COLUMN(A:A)-1)*2+2)
```

This will start in B19 and move over two columns for every column it is dragged over.

The `*2` is the spacing.

The `+2` is the starting column.

Comment: =INDEX('Initial data sheet'!19:19,(COLUMN(B:B)-1)*2+2)

When dragging right, its going =INDEX('Initial data sheet'!19:19,(COLUMN(C:C)-1)*2+2)

rather than being D:D?

Comment: No the `COLUMN(A:A)` is only a counter and has nothing to do with the starting column.

Comment: Agh, I see the logic now. Great! Works perfect. :)